# Pytest issue with fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to pytest and trying to use fixture.

I have the following code:

I am trying to convert the following logic to fixture:

I have a function called "kubernetes_.fixture" which is a fixture

returning me a function fixture. and then I make a list of those and send it to other function.

But, when I change the logic to merge to 2 logic in one fixture function 
I get the following error.

```
pod2 = (kubernetes_.fixture([samelink_pod2], namespace='namespace'))
pod3 = (kubernetes_.fixture([difflink_pod3], namespace='namespace'))
pod4 = (kubernetes_.fixture([diff_leaf_pod4], namespace='namespace'))
pod5 = (kubernetes_.fixture([diff_leaf_pod5], namespace='namespace'))

@pytest.fixture
def pod_list_fixture(pod2, pod3, pod4, pod5):
    return [pod2, pod3, pod4, pod5]

def test_same_node_traffic(pod_list_fixture):
    connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture]<<<< Never get ERRROR HERE
________________________________________________________________


@pytest.fixture
def pod_list_fixture():
    fixlist = []
    for pod in podlist:
        fixture = (kubernetes_.fixture([pod], namespace='namespace'))
        fixlist.append(fixture)
    return fixlist

def test_same_node_traffic(pod_list_fixture):
    connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture] <<< Get a Error here saying function object doesnt have attribute 'ip'
```

TRACEBACK:

```
pod_list_fixture = [<function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734268>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f96787348c8>, <func...>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734840>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734d08>, ...]

    def test_different_uplink(pod_list_fixture):
>       connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture]

test_remote.py:58:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

.0 = <list_iterator object at 0x7f965865c860>

>   connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture]
E   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ip'

test_remote.py:58: AttributeError
__________________________ test_different_leaf[kubernetes-1.8] ___________________________

pod_list_fixture = [<function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734268>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f96787348c8>, <func...>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734840>, <function fixture.<locals>._fixture at 0x7f9678734d08>, ...]

    def test_different_leaf(pod_list_fixture):
>       connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture]

test_remote.py:64:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

.0 = <list_iterator object at 0x7f9658649f60>

>   connected_ips = [pod.ip() for pod in pod_list_fixture]
E   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ip'

test_remote.py:64: AttributeError
```

Comment: Always include full stack traces in your question when you are asking about errors.

Comment: @jordanm I have added the traceback.

Comment: 1. What is `podlist`? 2. You shouldn't have to evaluate fixtures explicitly (I mean `kubernetes_.fixture`).